# Create a Table from Data

Tags: python, arrays

I have code that looks like this:

```
for x in rem_dups:

    gran = str(x[2])[-4:]

    if str(x[0])[0] == '1':
        print "+1: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0] == '2':
        print "+2: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0] == '3':
        print "+3: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0] == '4':
        print "+4: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0] == '5':
        print "+5: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0] == '6' :
        print "+6: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-1' :
        print "-1: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-2' :
        print "-2: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-3' :
        print "-3: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-4' :
        print "-4: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-5' :
        print "-5: ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == '-6' :
        print "-6: ", x[0], gran
```

rem_dups is a list of tuples, so x prints out each tuple that has three variables in it. How would I create a table out of all of the printed statements? I want something that is three columns and 12 rows - the three columns are the +6...-6 (these are hours before and after a prior condition) , x[0] for the given condition and 'gran' for the given condition.

Comment: You need to add some sample data, and add your outputs, and how you'd like  those to be different.  Otherwise it's extremely confusing to everyone else but you.  If you see code repeating over and over, like your if statements in this example, there's almost always an easier way to do whatever it is your trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

While your question isn't possible to answer the way you have it, I would like to show you an example of how you can reduce your repetitious code.

Replacing your if statements with something similar to this might help reduce clutter. It performs the same functions by reusing the same few lines of code over and over.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    if str(x[0])[0] == i:
        print "+" + i + ": ", x[0], gran

    if str(x[0])[0:2] == -i:
        print "-" + i + ": ", x[0], gran
```

Answer (score 0):

[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718350/chris) makes a [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36720553/3637833) on how the code you showed should be organized.

With regards to your question, you could create a list:

```
data_list = []
```

Then for each of the "rows" of data, you should append a dictionary to the data_list, as:

```
data_list.append({'lag_hours':"+" + i, 'condition':x[0], 'other_thing':gran})
```

Once you have this list, you can create a table using pandas:

```
import pandas
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data_list)
```

You can look at your data's head (top rows) like so:

```
data_frame
```

If you show a sample of what's inside rem_dumps (like print rem_dumps) I can give you some working code.

Good luck!